# Choose tableview cell programmatically in appdelegate does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using custom URL scheme to open specific view and choose specific cell of a table view. However, the cell choosing code don't work. Went through stackoverflow still couldn't find a solution

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

if ([url.host isEqual: @"help"]){
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabController.selectedIndex = 4;
    MoreController* more = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"more"];
    [more.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1] animated:true scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

whenever i open the app using url myapp://help , it only stays at selected index , and doesn't choose the cell.

Comment: Not 100% sure though, I believe you are trying to select cell little too early, rather pass the selected index to your MoreController and select it once tableView load is complete :) Like in ViewDidAppear or somewhere like that

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I'm applying in the appdelegate, so i'm trying to do in the conditions

Comment: ohhh god :) Sorry about my last comment :) The issue is buddy you are selecting the cell of the viewController which you instantiated newly :) But the one that is loaded already in Tab bar controller's specific index is different instance :) You should get the instance of VC which is already loaded in Tab bar controller and select its cell :) Hope my answer is clear :)

Comment: Find out the MoreController from tabController.viewControllers array, then try to call the selectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Write this if your `MoreController` is already loaded in `UITabBarController`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    if ([url.host isEqual: @"help"]){
        UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabController.selectedIndex = 4;
        MoreController* more =  (MoreController *)[[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:4];
        [more.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1] animated:true scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

Comment: There are already suggested answers in comments which your answer points as well, was there really a need to post it as answer ?

Comment: You are right but i think he require code for better understanding. if you don't like then tell i will delete my answer

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Yes, there is a reason to post an answer. Comments are not an answer. If someone chooses to post comments instead of answer, they have no reason to complain when someone posts an actual answer even if it is the same as a comment. As long as the answer is truly an answer, the existence of comments is irrelevant.